# MongoRepository Entity in StateServer

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongorepository

I have an MVC project with a `User` class that is marked `[Serializable]`.

This `User` class inherits from [MongoRepository's](http://mongorepository.codeplex.com/) "`Entity`" class as instructed in the documentation.

However when I try to save an instance of the `User` class to session, via StateServer, I get an error that the object is not serializable.

I'm new to MongoDB and MongoRepository so I'm not sure if there is something I can do here to make the instance of the user class serializable.

Sample code:

```
[Serializable]
public class SiteUser : Entity
{
   public string username { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
  MongoRepository<SiteUser> userRepo = new MongoRepository<SiteUser>();
  SiteUser user = userRepo.First(m => m.username == "myusername");
  Session["MyUser"] = user; // This won't work due to the "Entity" link.
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Why not just store the username and cache the `SiteUser` instance?

Comment: The base class isn't `Serializable.` All classes must be attributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `IEntity`, the Interface, instead of inheriting from `Entity` so you aren't depending on the Entity baseclass.

```
[Serializable]
public class SiteUser : IEntity
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string username { get; set; }
}
```

Also, since 1.5.1 the `Entity` class is [also marked as serializable](https://mongorepository.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/27172).

Comment: Rob, thanks for the reply.  This is what I had to do to move forward, but your example needs to have this above the Id property:

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]

Comment: "*But your example needs to have this above the Id property...*": As I wrote [here](https://mongorepository.codeplex.com/workitem/1444): "*no it doesn't*", *your* code/projects needs it, but it's not required *by definition* which is what you're implying ;-) An Id doesn't *have* to be an ObjectId. It could be anything from a GUID to a ISO3166 code to a phonenumber, e-mailadress, whatever_floats_your_boat. That's why IEntity exists in the first place ;-)